# Adding numbers from a list to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am still learning python and am having trouble writing a small block of code to automate some data entry. I need to create a large dictionary and populate it with different values and variables.  Below is an example, but I made the size of the dictionary small for this test scenario:

```
N = 3
newlist = [10,25,90]

config =  {f"C{i}": {'inletnode': f"J{i}",
                     'parameters': {'test1': 0.0013,
                                    'test2': 0.000846,
                                    'gamma': newlist[0]}
                     }
           for i in range(1, N + 1)}

print(config)
```

Essentially, this code works to populate the dictionary with values of C1, C2, C3 and J1, J2, J3 all the way up to N.  This works fine with the code I have, however, I haven't figured out how to populate the values for `'gamma'` with each element in `newlist`.

In the example above, obviously it will just print `gamma: 10` for each of the three iterations, but I have tried other approaches with no luck.  Below is an example of how I would want the output to look if everything was running correctly.

```
{'C1': {'inletnode': 'J1',
        'parameters': {'test1': 0.0013,
                       'test2': 0.000846,
                       'gamma': 10}},
 'C2': {'inletnode': 'J2',
        'parameters': {'test1': 0.0013,
                       'test2': 0.000846,
                       'gamma': 25}},
 'C3': {'inletnode': 'J3',
        'parameters': {'test1': 0.0013,
                       'test2': 0.000846,
                       'gamma': 90}}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

List indices start with `0` in python. You are iterating over a range from `1` to `N` (inclusive). You can simply get the `i-1`th index of `newlist` instead of getting the `0`th index all the time:

```
config =  {f"C{i}": {'inletnode': f"J{i}",
                     'parameters': {'test1': 0.0013,
                                    'test2': 0.000846,
                                    'gamma': newlist[i-1]}
                     }
           for i in range(1, N + 1)}
```

Or, for a more pythonic way, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). This function gives you the index and the element of the list you are iterating over. Specifying the `start` argument for `enumerate` adds the specified value to all the indices it returns, so you don't have to add it separately in your f-strings:

```
config =  {f"C{i}": {'inletnode': f"J{i}",
                     'parameters': {'test1': 0.0013,
                                    'test2': 0.000846,
                                    'gamma': gamma}
                     }
           for i, gamma in enumerate(newlist, 1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
N = 3
newlist = [10,25,90]

config =  {f"C{i+1}": {'inletnode': f"J{i+1}", 'parameters': {'test1': 0.0013,
                                                              'test2': 0.000846,
                                                              'gamma': newlist[i]}} for i in range(N)}

print(config)
```

Basically, you reuse the `i` variable to index `newlist`.

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand you, this is your solution:

````
newlist = [10,25,90]

config =  {f"C{i}": {'inletnode': f"J{i}", 'parameters': {'test1': 0.0013, 'test2': 0.000846, 'gamma': newlist[i -1]}} for i in range(1, N + 1)}

print(config)```
````

Comment: That did the trick, thanks to all and I appreciate the input and help very much!